# console.log inside a map in react component

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component, and I need debug the value of 'customer' element that 'map' produce "customers.map( customer =>".

I've tried before "" this

```
{ console.log (customer)}
```

but i get error, here the component:

```
const CustomersList = ({ data: {loading, error, customers }}) => {
    if (loading) {
        return <p style={{color:"red"}}>Loading ...</p>;
    }
    if (error) {
        return <p>{error.message}</p>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            Customers List
            { customers.map( customer =>
                (<div  key={customer.id} >Hey {customer.firstname}</div>)
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: You are currently using a `map` with implicit return. Hence you are not able to `console.log()` within your map. Checkout @MayankShukla answer

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `{}` with arrow function for [**block body**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) and put the console.log inside that, with block body you need to use return to return the ui elements.

Like this:

```
{ 
    customers.map( customer => {
        console.log(customer);
        return <div  key={customer.id} >Hey {customer.firstname}</div>
    })
}
```

As per **[MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)**:

> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block
>   body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is needed, and an implicit
>   return is attached. In a block body, you must use an explicit return
>   statement.

Example:

```
var func = x => x * x;                  
// concise syntax, implied "return"

var func = (x, y) => { return x + y; }; 
// with block body, explicit "return" needed
```

Comment: why '(<div  key={customer.id} >Hey {customer.firstname}</div>)' need parentheses ?

Comment: `()` are optional, we can remove that(not required), directly write `return <div>....</div>`

Answer (score 0):

A coworker showed me a trick to "log" out values not to the console, but rather to the browser, by adding another HTML element like this:

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(customer.firstname)}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a explicit return (as Mayank Shukla answer) is an option, but this is also possible with implicit returns (as the implementation in your question's example already have).

Hence [`console.log` always returns `undefined` or "None" / `void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log#return_value), we could use this to our advantage with optional chaining (`||`).

Example:

```js
const CustomersList = ({ data: {loading, error, customers }}) => {
if (loading) {
    return <p style={{color:"red"}}>Loading ...</p>;
}
if (error) {
    return <p>{error.message}</p>;
}

    return (
    <div>
        Customers List
        {customers.map( customer =>
            console.log(customer) || (<div key={customer.id}>Hey 
{customer.firstname}</div>)
        )}
    </div>
    );
};
```