# jsx console log inside map inside return statement

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm working inside a stateless function controller in React. I'm trying to do a console.log inside a map that is inside a return statement.
This works:

```
{options.map(o => (
   {console.log(o)}
))}
```

And this works:

```
return (
   <>
      //more html/jsx code
      {console.log("test")}
      //more html/jsx code
   </>
)
```

But how to log inside a map that is inside a return statement? like so:

```
return (
   //more html/jsx code
   {options.map(o => (
      <>
         {console.log(o)} //doesn't compile
         console.log(o) //doesn't work -> written in DOM
      </>
   ))}
   //more html/jsx code
)
```

Anyone have an idea if this is possibly at all. I find many answers articles/questions where they do 1 of the 2. Or in a map or in a return statement. Can't seem to find an answer that is both in a return statement **and** a map. I, ofcourse, only use console.log for testing purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are still able to console inside the map function.
But you should put console.log out of return JSX element.

```
const array = ['test', 'item2', 'item3'];
array.map(item => {
  console.log(item) // put your console here.
  return (
    <>{item}</>
  )
})
```

This will be duplicated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070282/console-log-inside-a-map-in-react-component)

Comment: Ignoring the "you shouldn't do a console.log inside a map inside return statement". Is it possible, and if so, how?

Comment: As you can see I am loggin console inside map function.

Comment: Anyone can try to log inside the map function to see iteration item.

Comment: In your answer the map is ***not*** wrapped inside a return statement, but the return is wrapped inside the map. I'm asking the reversed like explained in my 3th code block in my question.

Comment: I am just wondering why you need to put a console inside the return function.
Is there any reason you should do that? @control-panel

Comment: solely for testing purposes

Answer (score 2):

You are making an implicit return in this map here and returning multiple nodes at the same level. They should always be contained into one single node, so this:

```
return (
   {options.map(o => (
      {console.log(o)} //doesn't compile
      {console.log(o)} //doesn't work -> writes in DOM
   ))}
)
```

Should be changed to this: (notice the use of React.Fragment or <>)

```
return (
   {options.map(o => (
      <>
        {console.log(o)}
        {console.log(o)}
      </>
   ))}
)
```

Which makes a single node out of the output and lets react render properly.

Anyway, I don't recommend retuning `console.log` anytime in React, you could instead do the console logs and return a `null` so React knows that there's nothing to render in there.

```
return (
   {options.map(o => {
      console.log(o)
      return null;
   })}
)
```

Comment: There is content in my return statement, i just filtered it out to give the essence of the problem. I will make it more clear.